# How does bubble sort compare to selection sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Which sorting technique is faster: bubble or selection sort, and why? Are both equally efficient?

Comment: Are you on a mobile device in the middle of an exam or taking a take-home exam or something? Come on.

Comment: no..this question was asked to me in an interview.i said they are bubble sort.since in bubble sort consecutive elements are compared which are stored in contiguous memory location so it will take less time.Any opinion.

Comment: ...or both equally inefficient...

Comment: This came out for my exam last semester.

Comment: This is an awful interview question. It doesn't provide any information that a college transcript doesn't already provide (did you have a pulse during a basic CS course is all that can be gleaned from this question). Methinks that "Interviewing Programmers for Industry" should be a required college course for a CS degree.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) says (emphasis added):

> **Among simple average-case Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)
>   algorithms, selection sort almost
>   always outperforms bubble sort** and
>   gnome sort, but is generally
>   outperformed by insertion sort.
>   Insertion sort is very similar in that
>   after the kth iteration, the first k
>   elements in the array are in sorted
>   order. Insertion sort's advantage is
>   that it only scans as many elements as
>   it needs in order to place the k + 1st
>   element, while selection sort must
>   scan all remaining elements to find
>   the k + 1st element.
>
> Simple calculation shows that
>   insertion sort will therefore usually
>   perform about half as many comparisons
>   as selection sort, although it can
>   perform just as many or far fewer
>   depending on the order the array was
>   in prior to sorting. It can be seen as
>   an advantage for some real-time
>   applications that selection sort will
>   perform identically regardless of the
>   order of the array, while insertion
>   sort's running time can vary
>   considerably. However, this is more
>   often an advantage for insertion sort
>   in that it runs much more efficiently
>   if the array is already sorted or
>   "close to sorted."
>
> While selection sort is preferable to
>   insertion sort in terms of number of
>   writes (Θ(n) swaps versus Ο(n<sup>2</sup>)
>   swaps), it almost always far exceeds
>   (and never beats) the number of writes
>   that cycle sort makes, as cycle sort
>   is theoretically optimal in the number
>   of writes. This can be important if
>   writes are significantly more
>   expensive than reads, such as with
>   EEPROM or Flash memory, where every
>   write lessens the lifespan of the
>   memory.
>
> Finally, selection sort is greatly
>   outperformed on larger arrays by Θ(n
>   log n) divide-and-conquer algorithms
>   such as mergesort. However, insertion
>   sort or selection sort are both
>   typically faster for small arrays
>   (i.e. fewer than 10-20 elements). A
>   useful optimization in practice for
>   the recursive algorithms is to switch
>   to insertion sort or selection sort
>   for "small enough" sublists.

And, Wikipedia on [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) (emphasis added):

> **Bubble sort has worst-case and average
>   complexity both О(n<sup>2</sup>), where n is the
>   number of items being sorted. There
>   exist many sorting algorithms with
>   substantially better worst-case or
>   average complexity of O(n log n). Even
>   other О(n<sup>2</sup>) sorting algorithms, such
>   as insertion sort, tend to have better
>   performance than bubble sort.
>   Therefore, bubble sort is not a
>   practical sorting algorithm when n is
>   large.**
>
> The only significant advantage that
>   bubble sort has over most other
>   implementations, even quicksort, but
>   not insertion sort, is that the
>   ability to detect that the list is
>   sorted is efficiently built into the
>   algorithm. Performance of bubble sort
>   over an already-sorted list
>   (best-case) is O(n). By contrast, most
>   other algorithms, even those with
>   better average-case complexity,
>   perform their entire sorting process
>   on the set and thus are more complex.
>   However, not only does insertion sort
>   have this mechanism too, but it also
>   performs better on a list that is
>   substantially sorted (having a small
>   number of inversions).

Comment: The question did not mention Insertion Sort

Answer (score 16):

Selection sort performs a smaller number of swaps compared to bubble sort; therefore, even though both sorting methods are of O(N<sup>2</sup>), selection sort performs faster and more efficiently!

Answer (score 4):

while comparing these two algorithms we have to consider the two operations that are taking place in these algorithm
i)comparison
ii)swapping
on the basis of comparison operation both are equally efficient
but if you consider swapping operation you will find that selection sort is more efficient 
consider a array of size 100 in descending and we have to sort them in ascending order 
in this problem **BUBBLE SORT** will take 100*100=(10000)apprx swapping operations while in case of **SELCTION SORT** it will take only 100 swapping operations beacuse in selection sort at each iteration only one swapping take place

Answer (score 1):

Bubble sort algorithm is considered to be the most simple and inefficient algorithm, but selection sort algorithm is efficient as compared to bubble sort. Bubble sort also consumes additional space for storing temporary variable and needs more swaps.

Comment: I take issue with the claim that bubble sort takes more space for a temporary variable. With selection sort, a temporary variable is used to hold the min or max value. Isn’t that the same amount of space?

Comment: I also don't understand why Bubble sort consumes additional space for storing temporary variable?

Comment: I have issue with additional space claim as with clever programming you can go around additional space requirement

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to find a satisfying solution to this question here or elsewhere, though Senthil's [link](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/Sorting/selectionSort.htm) is headed in the right direction.

The question initially had me puzzled since bubble sort can be optimized by early termination of the outer loop after a sub-array (or linked list, etc) pass that fails to perform a value swap. Select sort can't be helped that way, so why would it outperform? Both are weak in general use - O(n^2) - so why isn't the one that can at least be marginally improved better?

The answer, based purely on examination of my own and other implementations, is that bubble sort does a value swap (read, write, write) on EVERY SINGLE COMPARISON HIT. Select sort just notes the new boundary value (min for an ascending sort, max for descending) and then swaps it out at the end of the pass.

```
void swapInt(int *ptr1, int *ptr2) {
   int temp;

   temp = *ptr1;
   *ptr1 = *ptr2;
   *ptr2 = temp;
}

/* compare and swap over a shrinking sub-array */
void bubbleSortArray(int a[], const int aSize) {
   int unsorted, i, iMax = (aSize - 1);

   do {
      unsorted = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < iMax; i++) {
         if ( a[i] > a[i + 1] ) {
            unsorted = 1;
            /* swap every time comparison is true */
            swapInt(&a[i], &a[i + 1]);
         }
      }
      --iMax;
   } while (unsorted);
}

/* compare to find min value, write it before shrinking the sub-array */
void selectSortArray(int a[], const int aSize) {
   int i, j, mindex;

   for (i = 0; i < (aSize - 1); i++) {
      mindex = i;
      for (j = (i + 1); j < aSize; j++) {
         if ( a[j] < a[mindex] ) mindex = j;
      }
      /* swap after inner loop terminates */
      swapInt(&a[i], &a[mindex]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though both of them have comparable and bad, worst and average case complexities, there are [certain points](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/Sorting/selectionSort.htm) which show that selection sort is better than bubble sort.

> The Selection sort spends most of its
>   time trying to find the minimum
>   element in the "unsorted" part of the
>   array. It clearly shows the similarity
>   between Selection sort and Bubble
>   sort. Bubble sort "selects" the
>   maximum remaining elements at each
>   stage, but wastes some effort
>   imparting some order to "unsorted"
>   part of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Bubble sort uses more swap times, while selection sort avoids this.

When using selecting sort it swaps n times at most. but when using bubble sort, it swaps almost n*(n-1). And obviously reading time is less than writing time even in memory. The compare time and other running time can be ignored. So swap times is the critical bottleneck of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In bubble sort we have more number of comparisons and swapping.

in an array of 10 elements we have 9 comparisons in first pass,8 in second 7,6 and so on. And in each 8 or 9 comparisons we are just able to swap just on element.

Where as in selection sort we first find minimum element of all and place it at 0 index of elements.

Complexity of both the algorithms is O(n2), but in worst case bubble sort has complexity O(n2) and selection has complexity of O(n2) and in best case bubble sort has complexity O(n) and selection sort has O(n2)